# DIC and Parameters

Tags: symfony

There's something that I'm missing.

Let's say I have a database from wich I start a new project. This database will be created after restoring a .dump file so it will also contain some "static" (static inserts from scratch db to populate it with "unchangeable" data) information inside it.

As this information will never change and as I need some of them (i.e.: an id for retrieve exactly a specific entity) I've thought to place them into a configuration file that is processed with the DIC & co.

First question: is this approach right or is better to create a *specific* .php file with some configuration values?

Second question: Why parameters I've defined through DIC aren't available?

I've create a folder called `DependencyInjection` inside my bundle, I've created `MyCompanyMyBundleNameExtension` file and create a `Configuration` file. I'm sure that files are placed in the right place as If I "remove" them all the things will mess up (just for people who will comment with "are you sure that ..." yes, I'm sure) I've also included inside my bundle "main" file the following

```
public function build(ContainerBuilder $container) 
{
    parent::build($container);
}
```

but if I dump (I use this approach as inside controller the exception "The parameter "xxxxx" must be defined. is raised") the config file inside Extension I can notice that is empty. Have I missing something?

---

## UPDATE

This is `Configuration.php` file

```
namespace Foo\FooBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * Generates the configuration tree.
     * 
     * @return TreeBuilder
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder() 
    {
        $tree_builder = new TreeBuilder();
        $root_node = $tree_builder->root('foo_bundle');

        $root_node
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('text_type')
                    ->children()
                        ->integerNode('title')->defaultValue(1)->end()
                        ->integerNode('description')->defaultValue(2)->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ;

        return $tree_builder;
    }
}
```

and this is the Extension

```
<?php

namespace Foo\BookingEngineBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Processor;

class FooFooBundleExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container) 
    {
        $processor = new Processor();
        $configuration = new Configuration();

        $config = $processor->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
        error_log(print_r($config, true)); //empty

        $this->remapParametersNamespaces($config, $container, array(
                      '' => array(
                          'text_type' => 'foo_bundle.text_type.%s',
                      ),
        ));
    }

    protected function remapParametersNamespaces(array $config, ContainerBuilder $container, array $namespaces) 
    {
        foreach ($namespaces as $ns => $map) {
            if ($ns) {
                if (!array_key_exists($ns, $config)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $namespaceConfig = $config[$ns];
            } else {
                $namespaceConfig = $config;
            }
            if (is_array($map)) {
                $this->remapParameters($namespaceConfig, $container, $map);
            } else {
                foreach ($namespaceConfig as $name => $value) {
                    $container->setParameter(sprintf($map, $name), $value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected function remapParameters(array $config, ContainerBuilder $container, array $map) 
    {
        foreach ($map as $name => $paramName) {
            if (array_key_exists($name, $config)) {
                $container->setParameter($paramName, $config[$name]);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

## UPDATE 2

If I run from command line the following `php app/console config:dump-reference foo_bundle` I can see configuration printed out. I'm pretty confused.

---

## UPDATE 3

I got it finally:

it seems that you need to specify at least one parameter into your config.yml main file, otherwise the "merge" option performed into `YourBundleNameExtension` will fail and return an empty array.

Subquestion: there isn't a method that I can follow to free me from write parateter into parameters.yml?

Comment: `Why parameters I've defined through DIC aren't available?`. Could you explain how did you define them through DIC? You could have added them to some of the `config_*.yml` files, added them to `parameters.yml` or defined them really in DIC through an extension or compiler pass.

Comment: @IgorPantović: I've used TreeBuilder (so a php configuration file as written in documentation) and Extension class

Comment: If you've created a valid config file and config array in extension is empty it means it's not included in DIC. So, you either forgot to import it or, if you're not in debug mode cache isn't cleared.

Comment: So in your Extension::load method you have code like: $container->setParameter('cerad_api01__bundle_dir',$bundleDir); ?

Comment: Exactly but the problem is before that because if I dump the configuration variabile it's empty

Comment: What about the $configs array passed to Extension::load?

Comment: @cerad it's empty and the "merge" result is empty itself.

Comment: Ok.  so lets go back to what Igor asked.  Please update your question with part of your custom config yml file.  This is all very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I got it finally:

it seems that you need to specify at least one parameter (related to your Config D.I. file) into your `config.yml` main file, otherwise the "merge" option performed into `YourBundleNameExtension` will fail and return an empty array.

Looking at my `Configuration.php` file, in order to make the code works without specify parameter directly into `parameters.yml` file, modify `Configuration.php` that way:

```
<?php

namespace Koobi\BookingEngineBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * Generates the configuration tree.
     * 
     * @return TreeBuilder
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder() 
    {
        $tree_builder = new TreeBuilder();
        $root_node = $tree_builder->root('koobi_booking_engine');
        
        $root_node
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('text_type')
                    ->cannotBeOverwritten()
                    ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
                    ->children()
                        ->integerNode('title')->defaultValue(1)->end()
                        ->integerNode('description')->defaultValue(2)->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ;
        
        return $tree_builder;
    }
}
```

the key is `->addDefaultsIfNotSet()` builder's method

### How do I went to solution?

Look at Extension file: you should notice the

```
$config = $processor->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
```

snippet of code.

If you open `use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Processor;` and analyze `processConfiguration()` method, you'll see that `$configs` - that represent `config.yml` content - will be merged to `$configuration` (that represent `Configuration.php`, so the DIC file that extenion will manage).
So the idea that a common key should be present somewhere came in my mind: after that successful check I've started to search for some methodology that helps me avoid the explicit process of writing parameters into `config.yml` (that wasn't what i want) and now all works like a charm

## SIDE NOTE

I still don't know if this is a valid approach so I'm not gonna check this as correct answer.